# How to prevent showing/receiving untranslated content?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

This is my Distance Cell

```
public function display()
{
    $this->loadModel('Distances');
    $distances = $this->Distances->find('all',[
        'order' => 'Distances.id ASC',
    ])->toArray();
    $this->set('distances',$distances);
}}
```

Problem, if content is not yet translated and stored in db, original untranslated content is displayed on the page.

How to prevent this, and show only translated content in current language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `onlyTranslated` option

This is unfortunately not documented yet, but the `Translate` behavior supports a `onlyTranslated` option, which will cause only those records to be found for which a translation in the current locale exists.

So it could be as simle as enabling that option, either in the configuration when loading the behavior:

```
$this->addBehavior('Translate', [
      'onlyTranslated' => true,
      // ...
]);
```

or on the fly:

```
$this->Distances->behaviors()->get('Translate')->config('onlyTranslated', true);
```

However, this will only work when the current locale is not the default locale. ie when you've switched the locale in order to view your content in a different language, in most cases however this is exactly what you want and need!

### A custom query

In cases where you want to retrieve only those records for which a translation exists, irrespectively of the current locale, or the locale of the translations, then a custom query with an `INNER` join on the translation table would be an option.

This should be pretty simle using `Query::innerJoinWith()`. Here's a basic example which should be rather self-explantory:

```
$TranslateBehavior = $this->Distances->behaviors()->get('Translate');
$translationTable = $TranslateBehavior->config('translationTable');

$distances = $this->Distances
    ->find()
    ->innerJoinWith($translationTable)
    ->order('Distances.id ASC')
    ->toArray();
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using innerJoinWith](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-innerjoinwith)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Translate > Using a Separate Translations Table](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#using-a-separate-translations-table)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TranslateBehavior::locale()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.TranslateBehavior.html#_locale)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TranslateBehavior::$_defaultConfig()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.TranslateBehavior.html#$_defaultConfig)**