# Cakephp 3 - Remove empty post from pagination

Tags: pagination, cakephp-3.0

I'm working on multi language website.
In the English version of the website all works properly, because I entered translations.

```
$blogPosts = $this->BlogPosts->find('all')->where(['BlogPosts.active' => 1]);
$this->set('blogPosts',$this->paginate($blogPosts));
```

If I changed the language of website I would like to remove all the posts whose translation of the title is not entered.
I tried this, but it does not work:

```
$blogPosts = $this->BlogPosts->find('all')->where(['BlogPosts.active' => 1,'BlogPosts.title IS NOT' => null]);
$this->set('blogPosts',$this->paginate($blogPosts));
```

Still printed posts without titles.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Check if your title without translation are `null` or are empty ' ' in database

Comment: How can I remove a post for any reason from Pagination array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent showing/receiving untranslated content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258910/how-to-prevent-showing-receiving-untranslated-content)

Answer (score 0):

Try this conditions:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate['conditions'] = ['BlogPosts.active' => true , 'BlogPosts.title IS NOT' => null, 'BlogPosts.title !=' => ' '];
    $this->paginate['order'] = ['BlogPosts.id' => 'desc'];
    $this->paginate['limit'] = 4;

    $blogPosts = $this->paginate($this->BlogPosts);

    $this->set(compact('blogPosts'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['blogPosts']);

}
```

Query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM blogPosts BlogPosts 
WHERE (
    BlogPosts.active = 1 
    AND BlogPosts.title IS NOT NULL 
    AND BlogPosts.title != ''

  ) 
ORDER BY BlogPosts.id desc 
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: It does not work. How can I manipulate with pagination array after the query is executed? Once the query is executed I want to remove some posts

Comment: What condition you want use to remove some posts?

Comment: @user3661042 try removing all `$this->paginate['conditions']` and just add this `$this->paginate['conditions'] = ['BlogPosts.active' => true , 'BlogPosts.title IS NOT' => null, 'BlogPosts.title !=' => ' '];`

Comment: @user3661042 I edit my answer with new query please try that code. if you want edit some conditions just remove, add or change array Conditions

Comment: $this->paginate['conditions'] = ['BlogPosts.active' => true , 'BlogPosts.title IS NOT' => null, 'BlogPosts.title !=' => ' '];.....
 
It does not work. This condition will never be met because the english version of the website title is not empty. Each post in english version contains title.

Comment: I need something like this:
    $blogPostsClean=array();
    foreach($blogPosts as $blogPost){
    if(!empty($blogPost->title)){
    $blogPostsClean[]=$blogPost;
    }    
    }
Of course, this does not work with pagination array.

Comment: @user3661042 as you say in preview comment  Each post in english version contains title. Then `!empty($blogPost->title)` is always true, I think you need make `if ($language != 'english') {$this->paginate['conditions'] = ['BlogPosts.active' => true , 'BlogPosts.title IS NOT' => null, 'BlogPosts.title !=' => ' ']; } else { $this->paginate['conditions'] = ['BlogPosts.active' => true]; }`

Answer (score 0):

I think faced with simmilar issue before. The pagination didn't worked as I excepted when I set order, limit together with custom where condition.

Try this:

```
$this->paginate['order'] = ['BlogPosts.id' => 'desc'];
$this->paginate['limit'] = 4;

$query = $this->BlogPost->find()
->select(['id', 'title', 'active'])
->where(['BlogPost.active' => true, 'BlogPost.title IS NOT' => null, 'BlogPost.id !=' => ''])
$data = $this->paginate($query);
$this->set('BlogPost', $data);
```